why systemd --user termination triggers check on every other systemd --user process?
I've a debian host with hundreds of users. Each time a user logs out, the user termination process reports a run-user-<user-id>.mount: Succeeded for every user logged in the system, causing a massive spike on CPU usage.
Also, using htop you can see that for each logged in user, there's a systemd --user trying to get CPU time.
This is a sample from the logs
systemd[1]: user@1172.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1172.
systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1172...
systemd[16425]: run-user-1172.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[8218]: run-user-1172.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[16968]: run-user-1172.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[19732]: run-user-1172.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[5342]: run-user-1172.mount: Succeeded.
systemd[19718]: run-user-1172.mount: Succeeded.
...
# 100 more lines like this

I've tried to reduce the impact on performance by enabling lingering (loginctl enable-linger) to all users in the system. Which effectively removes the termination process. However, the issue remains if a user is removed from the system.
Is there another way to prevent this user termination behavior? Where can I look for understanding what is going on here?
Thanks
